# Preventing mysql deadlocks in your php application that uses SELECT... LOCK IN SHARE MODE

Tags: php, mysql, select, innodb, deadlock

Stack:

If I understand SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE correctly, you can place it into a mysql transaction to select the rows you will be working with during that transaction in order to "lock out" those selected rows from other session's writing/deleting actions (but other sessions can still read the rows) until your transaction completes, at which point the rows that were locked with the SELECT LOCK IN SHARE MODE statement are released so other sessions can access them for writing/deleting etc.

This is exactly what I want for my comments table. Whenever a comment is added to a post on my site, I need to lock all the comment rows tied to that post while I update some meta data on all the locked rows.  And if two comments get submitted at the same time, I don't want them to both have access to the relevant comment rows at the same time because they will basically screw each other (and the meta data) up. So I want to incorporate SELECT LOCK IN SHARE MODE into the comment upload script so the first session to run the lock in query gets complete control over the comment rows until it finishes the entire transaction (and the script that was slightly slower has to wait until the entire transaction from the first script executes).

I am a but concerned about creating deadlocks where script A locks data that script B needs, and script B locks data that script A needs.  How can I get around this in my application?

Also, I am using only innodb in my website database, so I don't need to worry about table locks correct?

Comment: Please mark my answer below as accepted if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the MySQL documentation, the page [14.6.8.1. InnoDB Lock Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) discusses (near the bottom of the page) a deadlock situation caused by the first client requesting a read lock with "LOCK IN SHARE MODE" and the second client requesting a write lock because of a delete. The second client is blocked by the first client's read lock, so its write lock is queued up. But when the first client then tries to do a delete, the following happens:

> Deadlock occurs here because client A needs an X (exclusive) lock to delete the
>   row. However, that lock request cannot be granted because client B
>   already has a request for an X lock and is waiting for client A to
>   release its S (shared) lock. Nor can the S lock held by A be upgraded to an X
>   lock because of the prior request by B for an X lock. As a result,
>   InnoDB generates an error for client A and releases its locks. At that
>   point, the lock request for client B can be granted and B deletes the
>   row from the table.

If I understand this correctly, I think the problem can be solved by the first client using [FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) instead of "LOCK IN SHARE MODE". This causes the first client to get a write lock from the beginning, and then it never has to wait on the second client.

Use a transaction around the query and update statements, and the lock will be held until you commit the transaction. No other table locks should be necessary.